# Apply different properties on specific items in listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I fill a listbox `listBoxHome` from a dictionary `dictionaryHome` :

```
dictionaryHome.Add(item.Id, item.Name); 
listBoxHome.DataSource = new BindingSource(dictionaryHome, null);
listBoxHome.DisplayMember = "Value";
listBoxHome.ValueMember = "Key";
```

I also use the following code to be able only first 5 items to be `selectable`

```
private void listBoxHome_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InvertMySelection(listBoxHome, listBoxAway);

    //make only first5 selectable
    for (int i = 5; i < listBoxHome.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (listBoxHome.GetSelected(i) == true)
            listBoxHome.ClearSelected();

    }
}
```

[image]

I want to apply a different color to the first 5 items and different color the other items.
Or maybe a transparent panel that shows difference from the first 5 items and the other items. Also I want to draw a line inside the `listbox` as shown in the image. Any suggestion?

EDIT:

Adding Luc Morin's code the result shown in the following picture
[image]
Is there a way to show only the text and not the id(as was before)?The id is used in the back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set the `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed` in the Windows Forms Designer property grid.

Then, add an event handler to the ListBox.DrawItem event, something along those lines:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
    e.DrawBackground();
    // Define the default color of the brush as black.
    Brush myBrush = Brushes.Black;

    // Determine the color of the brush to draw each item based  
    // on the index of the item to draw. 
    if (e.Index < 3)
    {
        myBrush = Brushes.Red;
    }

    // Draw the current item text based on the current Font  
    // and the custom brush settings.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(((KeyValuePair<int, string>)listBox1.Items[e.Index]).Value,
        e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    // If the ListBox has focus, draw a focus rectangle around the selected item.
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Adapt to your specific needs.

Code adapted from MSDN sample at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx

Cheers

EDIT: In order to prevent selection of items, handle the ListBox.SelectedIhanged, something like this:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(listBox1.SelectedIndex >=3)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: When binding to a dictionary, the ListBox.Items collection actually contains KeyValuePair objects instead of just strings. I updated the code to account for this. My example assumes the Key is an `int` and the Value is a `string`.

Comment: @Apollon please edit your question, or use comments if you need clarifications. Don't edit the answer.